# Write or read to/from multiple files simultaneously in an unknown order in Julia

Tags: file, io, julia, contextmanager

I want to iterate over a text file's contents, which when analyzed determines which new file must be written to (and what its contents should be).

I have a working solution, (see code below) but I do not know if it is a very optimal approach. Specifically, I would like to automatically handle the closing of the files even in case of unexpected error. I have attempted to handle this case, but please see code comment:

> What if something goes wrong here, we could still have files in open
>   state right?

As far as I have read, closing files guards against corruption of the file. Is that correct? What are the other implications of having files unclosed?

If I can ensure files do not become corrupted, I can write code that can continue progress (maybe with some manual tweaks depending on what is found in the debug logs) instead of starting all over again.

**Working solution ([see jupyter-notebook instead](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1832467)):**

Question dependencies

```
# Ensure an empty directory for the execution of this question's code
tmp_dir = "/tmp/stackoverflow-question-55012211"
rm(tmp_dir, force=true, recursive=true)
mkdir(tmp_dir)


# Write example ".fakeq" files.
# In my real life problem, they would be ".fastq" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format)
# and sample would not be known at this stage, simplifying to keep things relevant to question
open("$(tmp_dir)/pool1.fakeq", "w") do f
    write(f, "id1_sample1_ACGTA\n")
    write(f, "id2_sample3_CGTACG\n")
    write(f, "id3_sample2_GTACTAC\n")
    write(f, "id4_sample1_TACGGTAC\n")
    write(f, "id5_sample2_ACGTGTACG\n")
    write(f, "id6_sample3_CGTATACGTA\n")
    write(f, "id7_sample2_GTACCGTAC\n")
    write(f, "id8_sample1_TACGGTAC\n")
    write(f, "id9_sample1_ACGTGTA\n")
end

open("$(tmp_dir)/pool2.fakeq", "w") do f
    write(f, "id10_sample2_ACGTAACGTA\n")
    write(f, "id11_sample1_CGTACGCGTACG\n")
    write(f, "id12_sample3_GTACTACGTACTAC\n")
    write(f, "id13_sample2_TACGGTACTACGGTAC\n")
    write(f, "id14_sample1_ACGTGTACGACGTGTACG\n")
    write(f, "id15_sample3_CGTATACGTACGTATACGTA\n")
    write(f, "id16_sample2_GTACCGTACGTACCGTAC\n")
    write(f, "id17_sample1_TACGGTACTACGGTAC\n")
    write(f, "id18_sample1_ACGTGTAACGTGTA\n")
end


# This array can be in the order of 10 - 20 elements long
csv_header = [
    "identifier",
    "sample_name",
    "sequence",
    "sequence_length"
]

# This array can be in the order of 25 - 50 elements long.
# In real-life problem, we know this list of samples up front
# and sample_name is calculated by matching an array of nucleotide
# 'barcode' sequences up against each sequence in the .fastq files 
sample_names = [
    "sample1",
    "sample2",
    "sample3"
]

# This array can be in the order of 4 - 12 elements long
# In real-life problem, we know this list of pools up front and each
# pool corresponds to a .fastq file mentioned above
pool_list = [
    "pool1",
    "pool2"
]


# I am creating a mapping here so that a file is written in a location
# dependent on the sample name

# What if something goes wrong here, we could still have files in open state right?
# If inside the try block below, then potentially some files will be attempted to be
# closed before being opened
sample_csv_mapping = Dict(
    sample_name => open("$(tmp_dir)/$(sample_name).csv", "w")
    for sample_name in sample_names
)
```

Main block

```
# An attempt to ensure that files are closed in case of error
try
    # Initialises (overwrites) csv with header
    for (sample, csv_stream) in sample_csv_mapping
        write(csv_stream, join(csv_header, ","), "\n")
    end
    for pool in pool_list

        # This automatically handles closing file upon error
        open("$(tmp_dir)/$(pool).fakeq", "r") do f
            lines = readlines(f)
            for line in lines
                identifier, sample_name, sequence = split(line, "_")
                sequence_length = length(sequence)
                csv_row = [
                    identifier,
                    sample_name,
                    sequence,
                    sequence_length
                ]
                write(sample_csv_mapping[sample_name], join(csv_row, ","), "\n")
            end
        end
    end
finally
    println("Manually handle closing files whether upon successful run or upon error")
    for (sample, csv_stream) in sample_csv_mapping
        close(csv_stream)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code the best option seems to `flush` the stream after every chunk of data has been written to the stream. This will force writing the bytes to disk and hence you can avoid the data loss:

```
flush(f)
```

#### EDIT

since you asked to help with editing your code:

1. The keys in sample names should be Symbols not Strings

```
sample_names = Symbol.([
    "sample1",
    "sample2",
    "sample3"
])
```

2. Edit the code to flush the file whenever the file changes could look like this (subject to further optimization):

```
        lastSample = :none
        open("$(tmp_dir)/$(pool).fakeq", "r") do f            
            lines = readlines(f)
            for line in lines
                identifier, sample_name, sequence = split(line, "_")
                sequence_length = length(sequence)
                csv_row = [
                    identifier,
                    sample_name,
                    sequence,
                    sequence_length

                if last_sample != :none || last_sample != sample_name
                   flush(sample_csv_mapping[last_sample])
                   last_sample  = sample_name
                end
                write(sample_csv_mapping[sample_name], join(csv_row, ","), "\n")
            end
        end
```

Comment: Where? After each  write? Would there be a performance hit or gain?

Comment: The location is usually a design decision if. If you `flush` too often you have a performance penalty because you do not utilize the buffering provided for streams. In your code I would suggest to do `flush` just before switching the output to a different file. However in some high performance computing scenarios flushing after each line is written might make sense (for example this might be convenient for logging).

Comment: In my scenario I do not know the order of writing to a new file. The .fastq files dictate which file must be written to. I guess the best I could do is flush after each 100 lines or something along those lines? If flushing, do I not have to close the file afterwards? What advantage does flushing have, given that in the code above I do guarantee that the opened file is closed?

Comment: flushing forces writing the data buffer to the disk. It is always nice to close the file but sometimes the process can crash and you can use `flush` to avoid the data loss.

Comment: I still don't see how to incorporate flush into the code above. Your answer is a great comment but doesn't answer all the questions I asked.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel Isn't the OS still sync the pending IO operations even on process crashing? The data are handed out to kernel space after the system call and is managed by the OS. I think `flush` only reduce the data loss on very rare scenarios like power failure, kernel panic, kill -9 etc. (Or when you use user space caching like [BufferedStreams.jl](https://github.com/BioJulia/BufferedStreams.jl)).

Comment: @BufferedStreams.jl - yes you are right system caching is a separate issue. Of course it can be also configured. However, Dean's job looks to be some HPC tasks, that probably sometimes fails or is stopped (probably by the job queue manager such as SGE or stops due to debug error). For such jobs those rare case scenario are the main problem to deal with. However, in order to have full write certainty probably some transnational system should be used (such as a relational database) - but this seems an overkill for this scenario.